# Random Number File Writer

Tags: python, random, numbers

Instructions:

- Write a program that writes a series of random numbers to a file.
- Each random number should be in the range of 1 through 100.
- The application should let the user specify how many random numbers the file will hold.

Here's what I have:

```
import random

afile = open("Random.txt", "w" )

for line in afile:
    for i in range(input('How many random numbers?: ')):
         line = random.randint(1, 100)
         afile.write(line)
         print(line)

afile.close()

print("\nReading the file now." )
afile = open("Random.txt", "r")
print(afile.read())
afile.close()
```

A few problems:

1. It's not writing the random numbers in the file based on the range the user is setting.
2. The file can't close once opened.
3. When the file is read, nothing.

While I thought the set up was okay, it seem to always get stuck on execution.

Answer (score 7):

Get rid of `for line in afile:`, and take out what was in it. Also, because `input` returns a string in Python 3, convert it to an `int` first. And you are trying to write an integer to a file, when you have to write a string.

This is what it should look like:

```
afile = open("Random.txt", "w" )

for i in range(int(input('How many random numbers?: '))):
    line = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    afile.write(line)
    print(line)

afile.close()
```

If you are worried that the user might input a non-integer, you can use a `try/except` block.

```
afile = open("Random.txt", "w" )

try:
    for i in range(int(input('How many random numbers?: '))):
        line = str(random.randint(1, 100))
        afile.write(line)
        print(line)
except ValueError:
    # error handling

afile.close()
```

What you were trying to do was iterate through the lines of `afile`, when there were none, so it didn't actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I ran the code I get this error                                                                   File "C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/ei8069_Assignment_Q1.py", line 19, in <module>
    afile.write(line)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object                                  What do I do? it seems it isn't writing into the file like I want....

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
ff=open("file.txt","w+")
for _ in range(100):
    ff.write(str(random.randrange(500,2000)))
    ff.write("\n")
ff.seek(0,0)``
while True:
    aa=ff.readline()
    if not aa:
        print("End")
        break
    else:
        if int(aa)%2==0:
            print(int(aa))
           
ff.close()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).