# Writing random numbers to a Python file and using newline to concatenate

Tags: python, file-io, newline

This program generates a user defined amount of random numbers and then writes to a file. The program works fine as written, but i want the text file use \n to concatenate. What am I doing wrong?

#This program writes user defined
    #random numbers to a file

```
import random

randfile = open("Randomnm.txt", "w" )

for i in range(int(input('How many to generate?: '))):
    line = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    randfile.write(line)
    print(line)

randfile.close()
```

Comment: `'\n'.join(str(randint(1,100)) for _ in range(int(input())))`

Comment: @roippi: That leaves off the final newline. You can just tack it on the end, but in that case, why not just do it as `randfile.writelines(str(randint(1,100))+'\n' for _ in range(int(input())))` and avoid the `join` entirely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random Number File Writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907759/random-number-file-writer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "\n":

```
import random

randfile = open("Randomnm.txt", "w" )

for i in range(int(input('How many to generate?: '))):
    line = str(random.randint(1, 100)) + "\n"
    randfile.write(line)
    print(line)

randfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

`file.write()` simply writes text to a file. It does not concatenate or append anything, so you need to append a `\n` yourself.

*(Note that the type would be called `_io.TextIOWrapper` in Python 3)*

To do this, simply replace

```
line = str(random.randint(1, 100))
```

with

```
line = str(random.randint(1, 100))+"\n"
```

This will append a newline to every random number.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is Python 3.x (see the `input` vs. `raw_input`, and `print` as a function), so there's no such type as `file`; it's actually something ugly like `io.TextIOWrapper.write`, which just inherits [`io.TextIOBase.write`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write). (It's unfortunately that 3.x doesn't have any simpler documentation for "file objects".) But other than that, good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make use of Python 3's `print` function's `file` keyword argument:

```
import random

with open("Randomnm.txt", "w") as handle:
    for i in range(int(input('How many to generate?: '))):
        n = random.randint(1, 100)

        print(n, file=handle)
        print(n)

# File is automatically closed when you exit the `with` block
```